# Как заставить IIS обрабатывать SOAPAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Работал работал себе SOAP под IIS 6 на NET 2.0, и спустя последнюю неделю начал выдавать такую ошибку (для запроса Soap 1.1).

> Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

1. Что можно дописать в web.config?
2. Можно ли как-то дописать обработчик заголовка?

Так как там очень много настроек, покажу web.config, собирал по кускам с разных источников.

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.web>
<webServices> 
    <protocols> 
          <add name="HttpGet"/> 
        <add name="HttpPost"/> 
</protocols> 
</webServices>
    <compilation debug="false">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <trust level="Full"/>       
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500">
      <converters>
      <add name="ConvertMe" type="Acme.SubAcme.ConvertMeTypeConverter"/>
      </converters>
    </jsonSerialization>
    </system.web.extensions>
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </modules>
     <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
     </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: IIS тут ни при чем. Для начала выясните, какая библиотека обрабатывает SOAP-запросы. Возможные варианты: ASP.NET WebServices (обычно это .asmx-файлы), WCF (обычно это .svc-файлы) - но возможны и другие варианты, включая сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Ваш web.config заставляет предположить что это - ASP.NET Web Services, но это может быть ложный след.

Comment: Ну и в любом случае - приведите пример запроса (главное - значение того самого заголовка!), а также класс предполагаемого обработчика этого запроса (код методов не важен, важны интерфейсы и атрибуты).

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, вы правы, о soapaction можно сделать вывод из исходников самой функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело не в Web.Config и даже не в IIS и не в Java и не в C#.

В C# SoapAction должно соответствовать определённому порядку,
если в функции указан namespace `[WebService(Namespace  = "http://tempuri.org")]` то в запросе  должено быть  **`SoapAction=`** *`http://tempuri.org/MyFunction`* (для функции MyFunction)

Исходя из моей WSLD

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<s:element name="GetMyValues">
<s:complexType><s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="region" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence></s:complexType></s:element>
```

SOAPAction должно быть `http://tempuri.org/GetMyValues`

Comment: Протокол SOAP тут тоже ни при чем.

Comment: Это просто соглашение об именовании, являющееся особенностью ASP.NET Web Services. Другие реализации могут выбирать другие способы генерации наименований.

Comment: Тогда я незнаю как это обьяснить, но для с# нужно что б то что в Namespace повторялось в soapaction. Я с удовольствием приму более красивое обьяснение в качестве ответа. Спасибо, этого я не знал.

Comment: Загляните в wdsl для своего веб-сервиса.

Comment: Заголовок SOAPAction выбирает операцию из списка поддерживаемых веб-сервисом. Клиент должен как-то узнать этот список (например, прочитав WSDL-описание) и передать серверу допустимое значение.

Comment: Хорошо, я поправлю ответ.

Comment: Такой сущности как "класс" или "метод" в WSDL нет вообще - есть только допустимые операции и значения action для них. А атрибут `[WebService(Namespace  = "http://tempuri.org")]` - это просто способ генерации имен операций, специфичный для выбранной вами серверной библиотеки.